# MFC DLL C++ How to create an executable that will run the DLL content

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, executable

I've been trying to create a MFC DLL where I basically put dialogs and stuff.

Obviously I can't run .dll file on windows since it is not executable so I need to create an app in c++ (I guess) that will run the .dll and it's content.

Btw i tried this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-compile-mfc-and-atl-code-by-using-clr?view=msvc-160

but I can't find the "Stdafx.h" anywhere.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Create the executable, and link against your DLL. You make the exported symbols known to the compiler by including the header file that represents the DLL's public interface, and pass the DLL's import library to the linker. It's pretty safe to assume that you neither want .NET nor the `/clr` compiler switch.

Comment: thanks for help, but what kind of executable do I have to create? blank c++ or mfc app? or clr app? thanks

Comment: Any C++ application will do. If you have MFC types in your DLL's interface, you'll have to link against the MFC libraries as well.

Comment: oh, so wait If I would want to link the mfc dll to let's say ATL project would that be possible? thanks

Comment: I know it's bad practice here to question the motivation of the one who asks, but in this case it seems all too confusing and the answer would benefit, if you would elaborate a bit on what you want to achieve in general.